# How to install only typescript dependencies and build (package.json, npm), avoid 150MB of dependencies when building

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I want to know if there is a way to:

- install only the needed dependencies to build avoiding 150MB of garbage;
- build;
- then remove the dependencies only needed to build but not for run.

*That's more of a doubt than a need for now*

I have the following dependencies:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.1",
        "commitizen": "^4.2.4",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "3.3.0",
        "eslint": "^7.12.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
    }
```

And I noticed something, I have a lot of useless dependencies when compiling typescript, because just to compile, I only need 3:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
    }
```

Only these 3 dependencies are like 60MB, and if I really want to, I can compile, remove the dependencies and use `npm install --production` what would let me with ~1MB, what is great for me, because the final can be as light as possible (a bit exaggerated, but cool).
Now when I do the full `npm install` with all dependencies, I reach 150MB (that's really disappoint).

My question is, there is a way, to minimize the dependencies install in the build process, other than moving types to dependencies (because they aren't "production" dependencies, only for "build")?

Actually when building I do this:

```sh
npm i
npm run build
rm -rf node_modules # not sure if needed
npm i --production
```

This will generate a small build, but in the process I will need to install around 150MB of unneeded packages.

Notes:

- I was thinking about removing it before build, but I want to avoid to do it
- I thought about optional dependencies, but looks like they don't have this purpose
- I want to keep the dependencies because they keep the code consistent when working with other people and help to avoid mistakes
- the "bigger" dependency is `typescript` with 61M and, the second one is `prettier` 20M, I need only `typescript` to build, but I don't need any of them to run.
- I just want to "solve" this when building, I don't really care about it when coding
- The problem here is not in the final build, is in the process that download unnecessary dependencies

Comment: why are you doing `rm -rf node_modules`? like is disk space the concern or needing to download them each time? because just not removing the node_modules would surely reduce how much needs to be installed each time.

Comment: I feel like your build process should probably look like `npm i --production` then `npm run build` with no other steps.

Comment: `install only the needed dependencies to build avoiding 150MB of garbage;`. Well, if you're building it, then those 150MB aren't garbage, they are literally the dependencies required to build your package.

Comment: @Adam as I said those 150MB aren't used in the build, they only help to develop the app...

Comment: @DavidNithaelTorresLima - if your app is written in typescript, then typescript is also required to "build" the application. It's not required to run it. Your `build` script no doubt includes the `tsc` command, right? All this being said, there is no distinguishing a "this dependency is required to build the app from source" vs "this dependency is just there for things like linting". A devDependency is a devDependency is a devDependency

Comment: Two problems here: I'm not just talking about typescript, prettier by example is a devDependency, but I don't need to build, and second, I will not need ts to run, so if a move it to dependency I will still install it to run, and that's not really ideal in this case.

Comment: @DavidNithaelTorresLima - my point is typescript **is an honest-to-goodness** dependency for building. You would not be able to build your application from source (to allow it to run anywhere) without the presence of typescript. My second point is that there's no way to distinguish between typescript (something required to build your application) and prettier (something not required to build your application). Though that does pose an interesting question

Comment: Oh, I see, you are saying something more like, there isn't an option to differ those

Comment: @DavidNithaelTorresLima like I said, you posed an interesting question. A quick google hasn't yielded an RFC for this feature (I'd call them "buildDependencies") or anything, but I did find https://github.com/itsthatguy/group-dependencies

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen as I said, I'm not sure if that was needed (wasn't sure if the flag would clean the packages), but my concern was if I really needed to install those other dependencies along at first.

Comment: @Adam oh thank you, that maybe never be implemented because the use cases aren't that many. I found the project that you shared interesting tho

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is not in the final build, is in the process that download unnecessary dependencies

Is this done in docker?

A solution exists for this - you cache the dependencies based on the content of the package-lock.json or yarn.lock

https://medium.com/@stepanvrany/how-to-build-nodejs-docker-image-using-cache-c401137661d0

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, and it could speed the process, but I still would need to cache those unneeded dependencies.

Comment: My real concern here is to know if there is a way to avoid it, but just out of curiosity.

Comment: @DavidNithaelTorresLima `if there is a way to avoid it` Nope.

Comment: That's kinda sad to be honest, but thank you, if someday I need it for any reason I may create a script to edit the dependencies before installing

Comment: @DavidNithaelTorresLima - the thing is, in a typical CI/CD pipeline, linting and testing are often done as part of the same CI process that builds the code from source. This renders the ability to install test dependencies, lint dependencies, and build dependencies separately, not very useful.

Comment: yeah I can see that, I was more curious